# c# what kind of design pattern should i use when a class has image and color property

Tags: c#, design-patterns, gmap.net

Actually,I work an application about map simulation,Element represent something with id and name:

```
public abstract class Element
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public abstract void Display();

    public abstract void Stop();

    public abstract void Refresh();
}
```

And Device is something like radar or radio device,they all have id and class,so Device inherit Element:

```
public abstract class Device:Element
{

}
```

and Target calss is something like radar station,radio station with a position property,

```
public class Target : Element
{
    public Position Position { get; set; }

    public List<Device> Devices { get; private set; }

    public List<Target> Targets { get; private set; }

    public override void Display()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Refresh()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Stop()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Position is a struct :

```
public struct Position
{
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lng { get; set; }       

    public Position(double lat, double lng)
    {
        Lat = lat;
        Lng = lng;
    }
}
```

There is also a class named Platform inherit Target,which means a ship or a plane,they can move from one position to another.

```
public class Platform : Target
{
    public double Speed { get; set; }

    public void Move()
    {

    }
}
```

All these classes should be in BL,that's no problem.But in UI, Device or Target should have Color and image proerty to show in map control(GMap.net,use image to GMapMarker).For the reason of split ui from bl,image or color will not allowed in BL.The question is:

Is there some design patterns or elegant way to handle this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design patterns provide general solution to commonly occurring design problem.

I would like you to follow below approach.

1. Understand intent of each pattern
2. Understand checklist or use case of each pattern
3. Think of solution to your problem and check if your solution falls
   into checklist of particular pattern

If not, simply ignore the design-patterns and write your own solution.
Useful links:

https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns: Explains intent, structure and checklist beautifully in multiple languages including C++ and Java

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) : Explains structure, UML diagram and working examples in multiple languages including C# and Java .

Check list and Rules of thumb in each sourcemakding design-pattern provides alram bell you are looking for.

As per your requirement I think Repository Design pattern is best for you.

Comment: Thanks! I will try your solutions

Comment: @wzj7531 if it is useful to you,then please mark me as an answer

Comment: Hi and sorry,I do not kown how to mark you as answer.Could you tell me how to do it.

Comment: @wzj7531 if you take the cursor bellow the down mark sign,you will see a right sign and then click it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign image and color to an element then you may have them in model(in your Element class). Initially they would be null but later you may assign them values. I suppose your models are shared between BL and UI.